# Hook up in cucumber check for scenario failure in java

Tags: java, ruby, testing, cucumber

While I was reading how to add a cleanup for a cucumber scenario on failure I got this piece of code in the internet.

```
After do |s|
  if s.failed?
    #If you are on an iOS Device
        $driver.quit
         sleep(time_for_driver_ready)
    #else
         reset  
  end
end
```

This is in ruby. I am working in java and is there any way to implement `s.failed?` in java, because in java the after method declaration does not include a scenario variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the Scenario as a parameter to the After hook, the framework will inject the current scenario object to the method.

```
@After
public void afterMethod(Scenario scenario) {
    if(scenario.isFailed()) {


    }
}
```