# How to call a function after failure of selenium,junit,cucumber and maven project

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have created a java cucumber maven project. Now I want to add a listener or any way so my screenshot capture function invokes if any of cucumber step/Test will fail.

I am not using `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` in Junit's TestRunner class. I have integrated `@RunWith(ExtendedCucumberRunner.class)`

1st try:
Here I tried to override below function in ExtendedCucumberRunner class :-

```
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public void testFailure(Failure failure){
}
```

But If I am trying to override an error is appearing as :

> The method testFailure(Failure) of type ExtendedCucumberRunner must
>   override or implement a supertype method.

2nd try:

I have also tried to extend `RunListener` class still it is not working.

The Code I am trying to add Lister is as below:

```
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;

import automationframework.AutomationLog;
import automationframework.ScreenshotAndTestNgReporterListener;

public class JUnitExecutionListener extends RunListener{
    /**
     *  Called when an atomic test fails.
     *  https://howtodoinjava.com/junit/how-to-add-listner-in-junit-testcases/
     * */
    @Override
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws java.lang.Exception{
        super.testFailure(failure);
        if (!failure.getDescription().isSuite()) {
            ScreenshotAndTestNgReporterListener.customScreenshot();
            AutomationLog.error("In Custom Failer Class of Junit");
            System.out.println("FAILED!!!!!"); //Here pass your screenshot capture event
        }
        ScreenshotAndTestNgReporterListener.customScreenshot();
        AutomationLog.error("In Custom Failer Class of Junit");
        System.out.println("FAILED!!!!!"); //Here pass your screenshot capture event
    }
}
```

3rd try:

I have also tried to add below rule in TestRunner class

```
@Rule
public TestWatcher watchman= new TestWatcher() {
    private String watchedLog;
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        ScreenshotAndTestNgReporterListener.customScreenshot();
        AutomationLog.error(e.getMessage());
        watchedLog+= description + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
        watchedLog+= description + " " + "success!\n";
       }
   };
```

I do not want to add @After method as it will call at every time even if any testcase success.

I want to capture screenshot only if test case fails

Can anyone tell me any way around so I can achieve same?.

Comment: You can do it in the After hook by passing the Scenario object as the method parameter. The current executing scenario will be injected by cucumber. The method isFailed() of Scenario will return true if the test has failed. Include the screenshot after checking this condition.

Comment: can you please share an example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919810/hook-up-in-cucumber-check-for-scenario-failure-in-java/44921078#44921078.

Comment: Cool it works.. Do I need to add that function in every stepdefination class?

Comment: No only once... After and Before hooks are called automatically by cucumber as long as they are included in the package mentioned in the 'glue' in cucumberoptions supplied to the runner.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Grasshopper .. It's working as expected.. :) .. You can post it as an anwser :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Grasshopper rightly point out. Use below function once in any of your step definitions. Cucumber will identify the hook and will run below function after each testcase run. In case it fails scenario will run the if condition and you can write any code you want to run after it.

By ref:

[Hook up in cucumber check for scenario failure in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919810/hook-up-in-cucumber-check-for-scenario-failure-in-java/44921078#44921078)

Code:

```
@After
public void afterMethod(Scenario scenario) {
    if(scenario.isFailed()) {

    }
}
```

Import:

```
import cucumber.api.java.After;
```